# Python preview (extension) VScode installation error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I install Python Preview Extension in VS code. And when I go to use it I get this popup window:

```
Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'
Origen: Python Preview (extension)
```

My VS code configuration is:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\anton_34bexlx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39",
    "todo-tree.tree.showScanModeButton": false
}
```

The path is correct, and I also restart VScode when I install it.

Comment: This extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dongli.python-preview. Did you follow this instruction? "*make sure the location of your Python interprter is included in your PATH environment variable*". That refers to the OS/system PATH, not `python.pythonPath`.

Comment: Exactly, it's that extension. And how can I change OS / System path?

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/q/284342/950877)